# Is there a more elegant way to add key/value pairs to a hash? (If key == nil, then assign new key/value, else add value to the existing key)

Tags: ruby, hash

Given a polynomial expression (e.g. `3a+2c-4a`), and its array representation `foo = [[3,'a'],[2,'c'],[-4,'a']]`, I am simplifying the expression by creating a hash and adding the coefficients as follows:

```
foo = [[3,'a'],[2,'c'],[-4,'a']]
foo_hash = {}
foo.each {|el| foo_hash.include?(el[1]) ? foo_hash[el[1]] = el[0] : foo_hash[el[1]] += el[0]}
foo_hash = {'a' => -1, 'c' => 2}
```

**My question**: can the conditional hash assignment within the `each` block be expressed in a more concise form that avoids repetition?

Comment: Please could you consider commenting if you downvote so I can learn from it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) with [Hash#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)

```
foo.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, (n,a)| h[a]+= n; h  }
# => {"a" => -1, "c" => 2}
```

Comment: `foo.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(n,a), h| h[a]+= n }` gets rid of that pesky `; h`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use of a default value in [Hash's initailizer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new):

```
foo_hash = Hash.new(0)
# => {}
foo_hash["completely_new_key"]
# => 0
```

So the concise solution becomes:

```
foo = [[3,'a'],[2,'c'],[-4,'a']]
foo_hash = Hash.new(0)
foo.each{|val, key| foo_hash[key] += val}
foo_hash
#  => {"a"=>-1, "c"=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `merge!` with a block:

```
foo.each.with_object({}) { |p, h| h.merge!([p.reverse].to_h) { |_, x, y| x + y} }
#=> { "a" => -1, "c" => 2 }
```